# triggering onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not able to get the below code to work.

```
$("#grid_table td:nth-child(10) input").live("onchange",function () {
    alert("changed");
});
```

am I missing something here? Thanks.

Ravi

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using and what browser? A bubbling `change` event in IE was introduced in 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `onchange` to `change`..

```
$("#grid_table td:nth-child(10) input").live("change",function () {
    alert("changed");
});
```

If that doesn't work I would verify your selector is working correctly.

Comment: selector is working fine as the following code is working $("#grid_table td:nth-child(10) input").live("blur",function () { alert("changed"); });

Comment: @Ravi how are you expecting the `change` to fire.. are you manually typing something and leaving the field or are you entering something programatically; a value entered programatically will not fire the change event FYI, also on most browsers the `change` event isn't fired until the field is exited with a modified (or dirtied) value.

Comment: I'm manually changing/entering the text and leaving the field. I basically want to know if the text has been changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$("#grid_table td:nth-child(10) input").change(function () {
  alert("changed");
});
```

to make sure your selector is working properly?

Comment: Being a huge Futurama fan, I love syncing your avatar pic to your name, just great!

Comment: Tried both the approaches, but its not working. But the selector is working fine as the following code is working
    $("#grid_table td:nth-child(10) input").live("blur",function () {
  alert("changed");
 });

Comment: @Ravi: sorry. @Quintin: Thanks! Glad you got the reference =D